# How to Convert Java Web Application into Gujarati Language

Tags: spring, internationalization

I want to convert my web application into Gujarati language.In my web application i use Spring and Hibernate framework.how can i do this ? Please give me solution.

Comment: You may need someone who is fluent in Gujarati - I only speak Java! But seriously your question is pretty broad, and asking "Please give me a Solution" without specifying which part you;re hvaing trouble with isn't a great way to ask a question. Have you done a search for "Spring Internationalization"?

Comment: The framework has nothing to do with the user interface language. Basically, you need to translate all text sentences one-by-one. Read up about internationalization to get some ideas how one handles multi-language applications.

Comment: I wont convert my whole web application into Gujarati language

Comment: @MattCoubrough I always thought spring was international and that translation would work all year round... ;-) Let's better play with strings.

Comment: I take it OP wants to know how to localize the app such that user sees content in different languages based on some autodetection or manual selection mechanism. Please see: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource

Comment: I guess all you need is resource files??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be using ReloadableResourceBundleMessagesource.
As for example, if you want the site in two different languages, say english and german, then create two different properties file, messages_de and messages_en.

Use a LocaleResolver to resolve the Locale and LocaleChangeInterceptor to intercept the request and set the lang value.

Follow this simple example :
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/

I will look into the possibilities of using some translation API and let you know if I get something.